# Mocking RestTemplate call with Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have the following code that is inside of a method that I am testing. I need to mock this `restTemplate` call to get predictable result.

```
GitHubEmail[] gitHubEmails = restTemplate
        .getForObject(userEmailsUrl, GitHubEmail[].class, oAuthToken);
```

In the test method, I do this:

```
RestTemplate mockRestTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

GitHubEmail fakeGitHubEmail = new GitHubEmail("testemail@email.com", 
                                 false, false, GitHubEmailVisibility.PRIVATE);
    GitHubEmail[] fakeEmails = {fakeGitHubEmail};

    Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.getForObject(
                     Mockito.eq(userUrl), 
                     Mockito.eq(GitHubEmail[].class),
                     Mockito.eq(testOAuthToken)))
           .thenReturn(fakeEmails);

    gitHubService.setRestTemplate(mockRestTemplate);
    User user = gitHubService.getUser(testOAuthToken);
```

Things aren't working as I expect them to... When I examine `gitHubEmails` variable in my method I am testing, it's `null`.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code, it should work. Are you sure that the `userUrl` is properly passed to the `githubService` as `userEmailsUrl`?

Comment: @g00glen00b I think so. That value is being wired in from the same property file through Spring.

Comment: Ah oh... You were right. I was wiring in the user URL instead of userEmails URL... Man, these stupid mistakes makes you chase your tail for so long. Thanks! I'd give you points, but not sure how through just comments. Maybe write that same thing in a response and I'll choose that as the answer. Thanks! Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes, I guess.

Comment: No problem, I encountered this mistake myself a few times. Rather than just copy-pasting my comment I also posted a little feedback in how you can make it easier to find these mistakes in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code as it is right now does not contain any mistakes. However, there are two things we don't see from the given code:

1. We don't see that `testOAuthToken` is properly passed to the `oAuthToken` variable within the `githubService`.
2. We don't see that the `userUrl` is passed to the `userEmailsUrl` within `githubService`.

You should make sure that all properties match the one you expect them to be, otherwise the mocking doesn't work. Given that you named one property `userUrl` and the other one `userEmailsUrl`, it's likely that the error is there.

Usually, when I encounter these error-prone mocking situations, I use *"any matchers"* (`any()`, `anyString()`, ...)  when mocking and then after the call and the assertions, I use `Mockito.verify()` to check if the parameters match:

```java
Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.getForObject(
        Mockito.anyString(), // Use anyString()
        Mockito.eq(GitHubEmail[].class),
        Mockito.anyString())) // Use anyString()
    .thenReturn(fakeEmails);

// Call + Assertions ...

Mockito.verify(mockRestTemplate).getForObject(
    Mockito.eq(userUrl), // Use eq()
    Mockito.eq(GitHubEmail[].class),
    Mockito.eq(testOAuthToken)); // Use eq()
```

The reason for this is that the `verify()` output gives a lot more feedback. Rather than just failing, it will tell why it failed when:

- The mocked method was called with different arguments, and which arguments
- The mocked object had different methods being invoked

Comment: ooooh. Even more value add in the answer. Thanks! That helps a lot!